# Can AIDE scan a directory inside a directory the user doesn't have read permissions for?

Tags: linux, permissions, security

I would like to use AIDE to help me verify the integrity of my home directory on a shared Linux system. I am not an administrator of this system. I have built and installed AIDE in my home directory and it seems to work properly.

The sysadmin has set permissions on `/home` to `0751`. This allows users to enter `/home`, but not list the contents of the directory.

For demonstration purposes, consider this overly simple aide.conf:

```
database=file:/home/kccricket/aide.db
database_out=file:aide.db.new
/home/kccricket R
```

Given this setup, running `aide -i` will output:

```
open_dir():Permission denied: /home

AIDE, version 0.15.1

### AIDE database at aide.db.new initialized.
```

The resulting AIDE database will be empty. If I run the same command with `-V255` (highest verbosity), I can see that AIDE examines every directory in `/` and then attempts to do the same with `/home`. It chokes because it can't list the contents of `/home`.

Is there a way to make this work, short of asking the sysadmin to change the perms on `/home`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to build AIDE from the current development snapshot or the 0.16a2 alpha release.

Version 0.16a2 includes a new option:

```
root_prefix
          The prefix to strip from each file name in the file system before applying
          the rules and writing to database. Aide removes a trailing slash from  the
          prefix.  The default is no (an empty) prefix. This option has no effect in
          compare mode.
```

In the case of this question, the new aide.conf file would be:

```
database=file:/home/kccricket/aide.db
database_out=file:aide.db.new
root_prefix=/home/kccricket
/ R
```

Thanks to Hannes von Haugwitz (hannes@vonhaugwitz.com) of the AIDE team for this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can have aide limit it's scan to only the folder specified by appending a `=`.

Example with your configuration:

```
database=file:/home/kccricket/aide.db
database_out=file:aide.db.new
/home/kccricket R
```

Change the line `/home/kccricket R` to `=/home/kccricket R`

That will force aide to only scan inside the specified folder, and not take a peek outside causing a failure.

Comment: That's an excellent suggestion that I hadn't thought of. Unfortunately, [it doesn't help](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1077024/)